# ABAddressBookGetGroupCount does not give proper count

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, addressbook, abaddressbook

I need to return all the contacts of particular groups. So have been trying to do some sample code which extracts all contacts. To start with needed to find all the groups in phonebook. When I opened phonebook, I observed that there are already 2 groups created because I had set up 2 accounts in **Settings->Mail,Contacts,Calendars viz**. `iCloud` and Yahoo Account.

Following is the code that I have written to get all the group names

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error)
                                                 {
                                                     // First time access has been granted, add the contact
                                                     // NSLog(@" given access..asked first time");
                                                     [self getContacts:addressBookRef];
                                                 });
    }
    else
        [self getContacts:addressBookRef];
}

-(void) getContacts:(ABAddressBookRef) addressBookRef
{
    NSString* groupName;
    CFArrayRef groups = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllGroups(addressBookRef);
    CFIndex count = ABAddressBookGetGroupCount(addressBookRef);
    for (int i=0; i<count;i++) {
         ABRecordRef record = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(groups, i);
         groupName = ( NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(record);
         NSLog(@"Group %d : %@",i+1,groupName);
    }
}
```

Now I should have got the count as 2 whereas I am getting 0. Can anyone suggest if I am doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() is returning kABAuthorizationStatusRestricted or kABAuthorizationStatusDenied?  Based on the code snippet you provided, a return value of kABAuthorizationStatusRestricted, or kABAuthorizationStatusDenied would drop you into the getContacts method without having proper address book authorization.